# Create a txt file with SSIS showing File Movements

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I need to create a .txt file every time and SSIS job runs and in that file I need to put the name of the files that I am transmitting.  I have a foreach container but I am not sure on how to create the file and then write to it as each file is being moved.  Can someone please steer me in the right direction?  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why you need the file names to be stored? You can use logging to capture more details of your activities.

Comment: One of the requirements is they want a text file that contains only the names of the files that were being transferred.  The reason is that they won't be sending the same files everyday but they want a record of what was being shipped per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1. Create a dummy empty text file
2. Copy the dummy file to new name `dummyfile_10252016` (using File System Task - need to handle it through variable to make the name dynamic)
3. Create variable to keep the `dummyFilePath`
4. Process your required files in `for each loop` and store the filename in a variable
5. Once your file is processed, write the name to `dummyfile_10252016`

Script task:

```
string filename = Dts.Variables["User::filename"].Value.ToString();
string path = Dts.Variables["User::dummyFilePath"].Value.ToString();;

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, filename );
```

[image]